mod $p$ local Galois representation attached to elliptic curves
In the paper, lemma 4.4. The author gives the form of the representation of $G_p$ on $E[p]$ of the form
$$\begin{pmatrix} \varepsilon\chi & *\\0 & \chi^{-1} \end{pmatrix}.$$
Do they assumed that the elliptic curve has good reduction?
They also said, "let's recall", so I assume this must be something a bit standard. Where can I find the reference to this statement?

This isn't clear to me either. I suggest you ask the authors.

This can't be true for primes of good supersingular reduction, can it?

Using Serre's paper, I can deduce more or less this form, but not exactly this form.

In the supersingular case you should get the representation coming from a character with values in $\mathbb{F}{p^2}$ and whose restriction to inertia is a fundamental character of level $2$. This representation becomes diagonal over $\mathbb{F}{p^2}$ but not of the form above (both characters in the diagonal are ramified).

If $E$ has good supersingular reduction, then $Ep\ne 0$ if and only if $e(K/\mathbf{Q}_p)$ is divisible by $p^2-1$. However, primes of bad reduction are more serious, by taking ramified quadratic twists you can certainly have $E$ where $E[p]$ has points over extensions $K$ with $e(K)=2$ but not over any unramified extensions. So the statement of 4.4 needs to include the number of primes less than $x$ which ramify in $E$ as well.
